# Eclipse Luna - Getting error - 'Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost. Multiple Contexts have a path of "/abc"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server.xml

I am using Eclipse Luna and getting

> Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost. 
>   Multiple Contexts have a path of /TestProject.

However I can fix this by making path for `docbase = /` in context string in `server.xml` as in context `docBase="abc" path="/" reloadable="true"` `source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:abc"/> docBase="xyz" path="/TestProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:xyz"/>`

So I wanted to know what role does attribute 'path' play in context and how do I fix it permanently. I have seen the path get carried over when I copy a application to another application.

Answer (score 10):

Go to [workspace folder]->Servers->[Tomcat folder] then open `server.xml` file and search for `<Context>` tag. There will be multiple `<Context>` tags, remove the duplicates. Restart your server. Hope this helps.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I've seen up to 20 solutions to this issue today and yours was by far the shortest and the clearest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the `server.xml` file. I had the same problem, and I just switched to a new workspace and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Go to *[workspace folder]->Servers->[Tomcat folder]* then open `server.xml`file and search for the `<Context>` tag. There will be multiple `<Context>` tags, remove the duplicates, something like this:

```xml
<Context docBase="service-name" path="/path of your service" reloadable="true" 
        source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:your-service-name" />  
<Context ................... />
```

so remove this second `<Context>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse tomcat, open server.xml and search "/abc", you will get this line, please keep only one and remove duplicate lines

```
<Context docBase="abc" path="/abc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:abc"/>
```